# MySQL won't enable InnoDB

Tags: linux, mysql

I am running MySQL 5.0.8

Recently (yesterday) my server host migrated my server and somehow in the process my MySQL got bonked.

After a bit of fishing, I believe the issue is that the InnoDB is now disabled for MySQL, and I cannot get it to re-enable.

Any help or direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

My my.cnf file is the following...

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
innodb_buffer_pool_size=64M

# Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
# clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
old_passwords=1

# To allow mysqld to connect to a MySQL Cluster management daemon, uncomment
# these lines and adjust the connectstring as needed.
#ndbcluster
#ndb-connectstring="nodeid=4;host=localhost:1186"

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld-bin
log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysqld-slow-queries.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[ndbd]
# If you are running a MySQL Cluster storage daemon (ndbd) on this machine,
# adjust its connection to the management daemon here.
# Note: ndbd init script requires this to include nodeid!
connect-string="nodeid=2;host=localhost:1186"

[ndb_mgm]
# connection string for MySQL Cluster management tool
connect-string="host=localhost:1186"
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue the below command,
`show engines` and check you are able to find the `INNODB` in that list.  If so, do the below command, and then bounce the DB

`SET default_storage_engine='INNODB'`